# Alors que + imparfait, passé composé ou imparfait

Tags: conjonctions, passé-composé, imparfait

> **Alors que** je **façonnais** tranquillement des meubles, B. **faisait** face à
> un grave danger.
>
> **Alors que** je **façonnais** tranquillement des meubles, B. **a fai**t face à un
> grave danger.

La première phrase pourrait être comprise de deux façons :

1. Je travaille le bois plusieurs fois de suite, et, à chaque fois, durant cette période, B fait face au danger.
2. Je travaille le bois ce jour-là et, pendant tout ce temps, B fait face au danger.

La deuxième phrase signifie que pendant cette période, B fait face au danger un certain temps. Je commence mon travail, un certain temps s'écoule, puis B s'expose au danger, puis le danger ne le menace plus, puis des minutes ou des heures s'écoulent, et j'arrête mon travail.

Est-ce correct ?

Comment: Je suis étonné de l'expression "façonner des meubles", il me semble qu'on emploie plus souvent "fabriquer des meubles". Je trouve des exemples où l'on façonne l'argile, une pièce métallique, ou encore des baguettes (de pain), une étoffe. Mais dans le contexte du bois cela semble avoir une signification différente : "façonner du bois qui vient d'être abattu, l'ébrancher, le scier de manière qu'il puisse être vendu".(https://fr.thefreedictionary.com/fa%C3%A7onner). Selon ma compréhension, façonner concerne le traitement d'un matériau unique, et non le fait d'assembler plusieurs pièces ensemble.

Comment: @LPH Je ne suis pas d'accord avec votre ajout. La structure de mes phrases est différente de votre suggestion, il y a une virgule et elle est importante. En fait, les phrases ont 2 parties. Je vais revenir vers ma version.

Comment: @Oreste Je vois, « + imparfait, passé composé ou imparfait » donne la structure de toute la phrase.

Comment: @Ben il se peut que vous ayez raison, le français n'étant pas ma langue maternelle. Mais voici ce que disent des dictionnaires : [lien](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fa%C3%A7onner) N. 2 _Fabriquer quelque chose, lui donner sa forme. Façonner un jouet, un outil; façonner un monument; façonner des briques, des tuiles; façonner à la main, au tour_. Antidote : Faire, fabriquer à partir d’une matière. _Façonner un vase. Façonner un bonhomme de neige._ Attendons d'autres avis...

Comment: C'est un(e) ébéniste qui parle ? Façonner donne un peu l'impression qu'on travaille une matière ductile, "molle". Le fait que ce soit un meuble entier surprend aussi. On façonnerait plus facilement un objet plus petit : *Alors que je façonnais tranquillement l'accoudoir d'un fauteuil, B. faisait face à un grave danger*.

Comment: @jlliagre Un artisan. Il est capable de fabriquer d'autres objets. Donc, il est préférable de remplacer _façonner_ par _fabriquer_ ou _meuble_ par _dossier_ ou _accoudoir_ ?

Answer (score 4):

Je suis d'accord avec ton interprétation, mais je ne pense pas que le sens 1. puisse être compris dans cette phrase, à moins que le contexte fournisse des informations dans ce sens. En changeant la phrase, on peut obtenir un cas où on comprend qu'on parle d'une habitude :

> Quand je rentrais de l'école, mon père partait au travail.

Mais à moins de parler de la vie d'un mercenaire en comparaison à celle d'un artisan, je pense qu'on comprendra naturellement "*grave danger*" comme quelque chose de ponctuel.

Donc je suis d'accord avec ton interprétation 1. et 2., mais dans la phrase on comprendra probablement le sens 2.

Je suis aussi d'accord avec ton interprétation de la deuxième phrase, le début et la fin de l'action ont lieu alors que le narrateur est toujours en train de travailler. Dans le contexte d'un roman, la première formulation est selon moi préférable. Elle est plus soutenue, et surtout immerge mieux dans l'action : si je lis "*B. a fait face à un grave danger*", je me dis que c'est terminé et que le danger a été évité. B. est hors de danger, donc l'impact de l'information est assez réduit.

Comment: Bien d'accord, la première phrase sera plutôt comprise dans le sens 2.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1):

C'est une question de contexte.

- Alors qu'il était en  visite chez ses parents, il n'y avait personne chez lui et il demandait chaque fois à un ami d'occuper de sa maison. (*itération*)
- Alors qu'il était en visite chez ses parents, il y avait une tempête en progrès qui est devenue très forte, ce qui le força à retourner chez lui plus tôt que prévu. (*ponctuel*)

Il n'est pas nécessaire que le temps soit à l'imparfait, le présent convient aussi pour cette notion d'itération. On voit ceci dans l'exemple suivant tiré de la littérature médicale ou autre.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Journal_de_psychologie_normale_et_pathol/1Ei7UTJ1pjoC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22alors+que%22&dq=%22alors+que%22&printsec=frontcover)) Le même phénomène apparaît aussi, et souvent d'une manière plus intense encore, dans les états hypnoïques normaux, **alors que** notre conscience est suspendue entre le rêve et la veille, que nous touchons déjà au rêve, quoique nous puissions ...

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Semitica/kSMIa4_KWtsC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22alors+que%22&dq=%22alors+que%22&printsec=frontcover)) Si, **alors que** tu fais une consultation en faveur d'un malade, les signes de ta consultation, à gauche, sont arrachés, ce malade guérira.

Dans le cas de la première phrase les deux possibilités sont réalisables, ce n'est qu'une question de contexte.

- Alors que je façonnais tranquillement des meubles, B. faisait face à un grave danger.

Par exemple, B est un enfant dans un parc pour petits enfants et il a la possibilité d'atteindre à travers la clairevoie le robinet d'un appareil de chauffage au gaz, mais A n'a jamais réalisé que cela pourrait arriver. Cette négligence a été répétée plusieurs fois.

Un cas unique est aussi exprimé par la même phrase.

Non, l'utilisation du passé composé n'exclu pas l'itération ; on peut même rendre plus précise l'idée d'itération en ajoutant un adverbe.

- Alors que je façonnais tranquillement des meubles, B. a **souvent** fait face à un grave danger.

Le choix entre l'imparfait et le passé composé (littéraire, le passé simple) est seulement un choix entre une action en toile de fond et une action au premier plan ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_de_l%27indicatif_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Utilisation)).